# How do I pipe 7za output directly to psql?

Tags: 7-zip, postgresql, 7za

I have a Postgres database dump in a .7z archive.

I can extract it and import it with:

```
7za e dump.7z dump
psql -h localhost db_name < dump
```

but I'm just running out of disk space.

What is the correct way to pipe the 7za output to psql, so that I don't have a large temporary file taking up space?

Answer (score 0):

If it's similar to importing from a `.gz` file, then you're looking to pipe the output from `7za` into `psql` with something like this:

```
7za e dump.7z | psql -h localhost db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-so` option for 7za.

```
7za e -so dump.7z | psql -h localhost -U admin db_name
```